# Swift - unable to play live stream video using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I am trying to figure out why i am getting this view:
[image]

In view did load i am doing so:

```
                    let url = URL(string: url)
                    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url!)
                    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
                    self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
                    self.avpController.player =  self.player
                    self.present(self.avpController, animated: true) {
                        self.avpController.player?.play()
                  }
```

The only thing that make cense is that the url is no good, yet it works in the browser(not in the safari) and vlc player:

Any ideas will help

https://www.name.name/http-name/eyJraWQiOiJmbGlyIiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.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.CWhDIwZkZDkM322y_0-9FoFdrksNcBKgPUayqX5G8K7yWkoGDvACgMnVI4RLtcLBmHaFDq3ojHB-5BVVCZ3Wgq5CIBWboE3cH5aLNR08qse8wp8UcLdlqgFBDzSCa2XxGl3jWomtalhGaG2rEhT4sxLMTJhCL7Ok0emtlNlJ_b5uU7AAEuYyu7jGgOqU0e2a-uOgOGIBGSSv8RiJdBB33R-SQxWKwOwDqOxBVv0FRld6pdi6E8MBLG45gPhTif7_24bfK57JWf8WiirK4dIHKfEJBY5Kp9zcvvQRRlGmoHrTbC6djlnPQc

Comment: I doubt that your video URL is supported by the player. Try any URL which end with .mp4

Comment: @Shubham tried that and it is working...
the question is how can i play it and why does it works in the web and VLC player

Comment: AVPlayer only supports the URL which points directly to the media file.

Comment: @Shubham any other players or solutions you recommend ?

Comment: trying to show the video URL in webview may helpful.

Comment: @Shubham, nice idea, btw what is tvideo?

Comment: mistyped, corrected.

Comment: @Shubham, thanks! i will try and hope it will work :)(if so i will ask you to post answer so i will mark it)

Comment: @Shubham so i tried it with WKWebView but no success, any more ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187096/discussion-between-shubham-and-ironroei).

Comment: @Shubham, hi. i am there

Comment: @Shubham the url generated after a couple of calls.
you want to generate one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after one day i have managed to do it.
i used this excellent guide to play it with vlc player: https://hackernoon.com/swift-4-ios-app-player-live-stream-video-from-nginx-nginx-rtmp-use-vlckit-f2162134ae5c